# Ways to detect close proximity ( ~15cm) of several individual child objects to a mother object

Tags: bluetooth, electromagnetic, proximity

I'm working on a design project for a university course exam where several small child objects have to detect whether they are in close proximity (~15cm) to a central mother object and switch their LED's between two solid colors, independently of each other. Preferably, the children should be kept as simple and energy efficient as possible. I have enclosed a picture demonstrating this feature.

I'm not well versed in electronics (that's a later course), but so far I've considered electromagnetic tracking, bluetooth and NFC.
NFC is too short range for my purposes.
Electromagnetism seems like a simple solution, but I wouldn't be surprised if it isn't simple.
My friend recommended bluetooth, which should do the trick nicely, but it seems like a lot of complexity and wasted functionality for one LED with two states, and I'm concerned about power drain and price (might be an outdated notion).

[image: Visualization of intended function]

Comment: It is indeed a lot of complexity, but the advantage of using something like it is that the complexity is already done. Someone else already made the complexity. So sometimes using a thing like Bluetooth is easier.

Comment: I agree you can do this with RF or infrared. Note that with RF you will have to check the licensing rules to see what frequency you can use. Infrared requires line-of-sight and RF can also be blocked by metal objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the site, BBlaze! You've presented an interesting design exercise with many possible solutions. Let's expand your initial thoughts into a matrix. The rows of the matrix represent the types of energy transmitted, i.e:

- Optical (e.g. infrared, visible light)
- Radio (e.g. LF/HF/VHF/UHF radio, WiFi, Bluetooth, UWB, radar, etc)
- Electric/Magnetic (e.g. induction, capacitance)
- Acoustic (e.g. audible sound, ultrasound)

The columns of the matrix represent how we could measure distance of a signal arriving, e.g.:

- Signal strength
- Signal timing
- Signal angle of arrival

Some of the matrix cells are tougher than others. For example, measuring distance accurate to a few centimeters by timing the arrival of optical or radio waves traveling at the speed of light requires sub-nanosecond pulses and timing accuracy -- tough (although doable with advanced components). Signal strength sounds easier, but for optical and radio waves you'd need accurate, omnidirectional lenses or antennas.

Meanwhile, there are some tricks you may not have considered. If the "mother" is tall as you illustrated, you can use the difference in distances between a low profile "child" and the top and bottom of the "mother" to triangulate the horizontal distance.

Here are two approaches I find interesting, from a low cost and simplicity standpoint, for you to further investigate:

1. Magnetic field. Stand a cylindrical magnet upright in the "mother" and just measure the z-axis magnetic field strength (using a magnetometer chip) in the "child". Or use a vertical solenoid coil in the "mother" excited with 1 kHz; put vertical detection coil in the "child" and measure the 1 kHz signal strength; very simple circuitry.
2. Ultrasound. Put ultrasound transducers at top and bottom of "mother" excited with the same pulse. Put ultrasound receiver at the bottom of the "child". You'll receive 2 pulses for each "mother" pulse, and the delay between them will be a geometric function of the distance. Circuit somewhat more involved, but you can use ultrasonic distance measuring modules as sources of parts and schematics.

Keep pushing yourself for more ideas, as that is the purpose of the exercise. Hmm... what about a conical prism at the top of the "mother" that would spread an internal white light source into concentric bands of spectral color on the table, for detection by the "children".